# Equivalent of jQuery .offset().top in D3

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to understand how to get the distance of an element to the top of a document -- only with D3.js.

In jQuery, the answer is: `$("el").offset().top;`

What's the D3 way?

Comment: There's no direct equivalent in D3.

Comment: Any sense if D3 can be used to simplify the calculation?

Comment: I wouldn't think so -- `.offset().top` is quite simple already :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoffI mean, what's another library :)..

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: pageYOffset is one easy solution, sometimes used by Bostock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid jQuery, best to just use native javascript code:

So:

`el.getBoundingClientRect().top`

And:

`pageYOffset`

These can compared to create scroll-based event triggers.